# ¿Como instalar Font Awesome 5 en Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular5, font-awesome, angular6

Como no utilizo ***yarn*** busque por ***npm*** (***[enlace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome)***).

En ***src/app/app.module.ts***

> Import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome'

Lo agrego a los ***imports***

> FontAwesomeModule

Y esto me causa el siguiente error por consola:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'
>     at syntaxError (compiler.js:1016)
>     at compiler.js:10584
>     at Array.forEach ()
>     at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:10553)
>     at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:23850)
>     at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23831)
>     at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:23791)
>     at CompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:143)
>     at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:4352)
>     at Object../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)

***Actualización 1:***

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component';
import { ConversorPipe } from './pipes/conversorMayusMinus.pipe';
import { ErrorComponent } from './components/error.component';

import { CategoriaComponent } from './components/categoria.component';
import { ColorComponent } from './components/color.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ConversorPipe,
    ErrorComponent,
    CategoriaComponent,
    ColorComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***Actualización 2:***

Cambiar la siguiente linea de código

> import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';

por esta :

> import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

Esto me genera el siguiente error:

> ./node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/fesm5/angular-fontawesome.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' in 'C:\wamp64\www\webapp\node_modules\@fortawesome\angular-fontawesome\fesm5'

***Actualización 3:***
Agregar:

> import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

Me genera el siguiente error:

[image: error]

***Actualización 4:***

Siguiendo la sugerencia de ***[@LPZadkiel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201587/como-instalar-font-awesome-5-en-angular-6/201614#201614)***.
[image: error]

Comment: puedes mostrar el codigo de los imports, aparentemente es un error de sintax o alguna coma, muestra el js donde haces estos imports.

Comment: @TheVicious agregado.

Comment: puedes cambiar la siguiente linea de código import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free'; por esta : import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome'; ensaya y me dices que sucede.

Comment: @TheVicious actualizado el nuevo error.

Comment: agrega esto import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'; debajo del import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

Comment: para instalar fontawesome hiciste esto? `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`, te aseguraste de hacerlo en la carpeta del proyecto?

Comment: @TheVicious actualizado

Comment: @LPZadkiel si, a ambas preguntas.

Comment: @PabloContreras con la solución que te di ya no debes importarlo, debes usarlo como un framework mas al estilo bootstrap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En vista y considerando que estas usando `npm` y no `yarn` pues no tienes otra opción mas que usar los iconos al estilo `html`. Debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma

ejecutar

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

luego en el archivo `angular.json` agregar lo siguiente

```
        "styles": [
           "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
        ]
```

o esto (cualquiera de las dos opciones sirve)

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js"
        ]
```

y luego los usas agregando los iconos en los html:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i>
```

es solo agregar la class por lo que aun puedes hacerlo desde los archivos `typescript`

**NOTA: Con esta solución no debes hacer un `import { FontAwesomeModule } from ...` solo agregas el archivo `all.css` o `all.js` (solo uno no ambos) y lo empiezas a usar con las class en los elementos html `<i>`**

Comment: ¿Como puedo actualizarlo a font-awesome 5+?

Comment: con la línea `npm install...` si no asignas una versión te descargará automáticamente la última versión. Yo hice la prueba y me descargó la versión 5.3.1

Comment: Pregunte por la actualización porque chequee en el ***package,json***, en las ***"dependencies"*** dice **"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",**, Hay algo que me causa el problema que ahora me presenta.

Comment: no sabría decirte, a mi me descargó la última versión, prueba con esto `npm install FortAwesome/Font-Awesome@5.3.1`

Comment: Verifique el archivo en **node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css** y, efectivamente, es la ultima versión. Ya no importo en ***app.module*** sino que lo hago como tu dices. Sin embargo persiste el error que te muestro en pantalla.

Comment: si te sigue mostrando el error quizás sea porque aun esta intentando compilar un no componente existente de font awesome, intenta deteniendo el servidor y ejecutarlo de nuevo (ng serve)

Comment: Quite ***import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';*** y si anda sin problema. El problema es que necesito esa librería para un botón que utilizo.

Comment: según tengo entendido, bootstrap no se importa como un módulo, se importa exactamente igual a lo que te mostré en esta respuesta, en mi `angular.json` yo tengo lo siguiente bajo el parámetro de mi proyecto: `"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],`

Comment: Listo, fue la solución. Gracias hermano.

Comment: a mi me sirvio usando este comando: npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free